# Android EditText moving when MultiLine in TableRow

Tags: android, android-edittext, tablelayout, tablerow

I have a Tablelayout with many TableRows inside. And inside these TableRows, many EditText. Like a spreadsheet.

My problem is the following: when something is wrote in the EditBox, the EditBoxs are still aligned:

[image: EditBox aligned]

But when the content of the EditBox goes to multi-line, my EditBox are not aligned anymore:
[image: EditBox not aligned]

I thought that maybe the problem comes from the fact that my EditBox is not centered vertically in my TableRow, but this is something that I couldn't do.

Here is my code for the EditText, I add dynamically each EditText in my TableRows:

```
private EditText editTextCellule(int num, String texte, boolean pair){

            EditText cellule = new EditText(this);

            cellule.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(num));
            cellule.setWidth(LARGEUR_CELLULE);
            cellule.setHeight(HAUTEUR_CELLULE);
            cellule.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size_medium_minus));
            cellule.setText(texte);
            cellule.setKeyListener( new PerfKeyListener() );

            return cellule;
    }
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You provide layout weight to the following rows so they won't move.....

android:layout_weight = "1"

in table rows....

Comment: Set weight to my table rows? How can I do that programatically?